# How to deal with cross-domain concepts in DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Let's say I have a class that provides calculations or concepts that are used by different domains. Since domains are in their own "bubble" and have no idea about the outside, I would have to copy this class in every domain, right? Or is there such a thing as a utility domain? I would like to avoid maintaining the same class in several domains.

I'll try to give an example: Suppose I have invented a new concept of time. An hour no longer lasts 60 minutes, but about 70. A day now lasts about 22 hours and also the date looks different. Now I want to build a store system with the following subdomains: Order, Contract, Delivery, and Invoice. Each subdomain now uses this new time concept. Whenever a time unit is needed, the new time concept should be used. This can happen in all subdomains.

Answer (score 1):

If this elements (classes, functions etc) are shared between several sub-domains, you could build a shared domain. Better would be if this elements are part of a named shared domain so it's not just 'shared'.

For example, you could have to manage entities like **Car**, **Motorbike** and **Bus**. All this entities, after some analysis, share some elements. For example, they all have  an *Engine*, *Tire* (more than one), an *IdSign*. You can share all this elements in a common entity, **Vehicle**. All the entities derive from this, and extend/improve it's base functions. In this way you build a shared domain that is extended by the other domains.

On the other side, you could have this functions totally disjointed from the entities of the domain. I mean, you could have a function 'find the number of minutes between two (local) hours' that is totally disconnected from the **Vehicle** and it's sub entities. This kind of elements should stay in an *utility* package, that live it's own life and is used inside the domain that you're going to design.

But, if you are going to design something around the **Clock** entity, the same function of before would be placed in a totally different package.

That means, the best solution for your problem depends totally on your domain and the way you're going to design it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added an example to my question. So in this case I should build a library that contains the new time concept and all needed utility classes for time calculation?

Comment: Yes. Within your example, you have a whole new way to handle the Dates and Times. Hence, you would have a new whole library (let's call it SuperTime), that is shared within all the elements of the domain and is also totally unrelated (in terms of lifecyle) from the domain itself.  You could add bugfixes, new features, etc, all without being directly involved in what is your domain. On the other side, within your domain you could choose to upgrade to a new version or not, but this (except from bugs) would not change any of its functionalities. It still works as expected.

Comment: But, as I said before, it depends on the way you intend your domain. If this way to handle the Dates and Times is specifically built for your domain, that means that the domain requires to handle the Dates and Times in this way, the story is different. Here you would have a shared domain, with some common elements (if exits), that has as its own roots this way of managing the Dates and Times. Any change in this shared domain is reflected in an immediate change in each related sub-domains.

Comment: It all depends in the way you design it and you are going to use it. I would suggest you to investigate deeply enough the domain before going on one route or another. On the other side, avoid too many assumptions about things that you still don't know deeply enough.